# Date format keeps changing once saved to .csv file from Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df,  that was transformed using Python:

```
df.insert(loc = 0, column = 'date', value =  '2019-10-01')


date

2019-10-01
```

However, when I save this to my computer as a .csv file, the transformation changes back to the undesired format:

```
df.to_csv(r'F:\\df_new.csv', index = False)


date

10/01/2019
```

How would I avoid this and have the .csv in the correct format such as:

```
date

2019-10-01
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `date_format` parameter of to_csv method as

```
 df.to_csv(filename, date_format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Thanks A.B. but it did not change. The date format is still 10/01/2019  . I did this:  df.to_csv(r'F:\\BackupOct2019.csv', date_format='%Y-%m-%d', index = False).

Comment: can you try to convert your datetime first? `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])` and let me know?

Comment: Ok I just converted to datetime and then ran the date_format code but the format is still the same when I open the csv file

Comment: are you sure you are opening correct csv file? try deeleting the old one first

Comment: Also see it in notepad/text-editor, is it the same?

Comment: I am pretty sure, but I will save as a diff file

Answer (score 1):

.to_csv() has a 'date_format' argument that you can specify to retain formatting when writing the csv.